# Conemu Msys2-64 task doesn't have the right PATH

Tags: windows-7, conemu, msys

On `ConEmu 161206 [64] {Stable}` there is a task called `{Bash:Msys2-64}` whose content is:

```
set CHERE_INVOKING=1 & C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe --login -i -new_console:C:"C:\msys64\msys2.ico"
```

If I run this conemu task and query PATH I get:

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

While if I run msys2 for 64bit using `> msys2_shell.cmd -mingw64` I'll get:

> /mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

As you can see PATH created by the conemu task isn't matching the one created by `msys2_shell.cmd -mingw64` (missing /mingw64/bin), problem with this is you won't be able to run tools like cmake living in `/mingw64/bin`.

So the question is, how can i change the conemu `{Bash:Msys2-64}` task so it will create the exact same PATH than the one created by `msys2_shell.cmd -mingw64`?

Comment: Try `sh.exe` instead of `bash.exe`.

Comment: @Maximus Same outcome, replacing bash with sh on `{Bash:Msys2-64}` will create a PATH without `/mingw64/bin`. I needed msys2 in order to compile a python package with some posix stuff and I did it by adding manually `PATH=$PATH;/mingw64/bin`... Ideally I'd be able to have the right path when spawning msys2 from conemu, that'd be great

Comment: Simple check of the `msys2_shell.cmd` contents would gave you an answer. The batch file sets environment variable `set MSYSTEM=MINGW64`.